# In lxml Python 3 how to recursively all the linked ids

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, xml-parsing, lxml

I have an xml like this:

```
<library>
    <content content-id="title001">
        <content-links>
            <content-link content-id="Number1" />
            <content-link content-id="Number2" />
        </content-links>
    </content>
    <content content-id="title002">
        <content-links>
            <content-link content-id="Number3" />
        </content-links>
    </content>
    <content content-id="Number1">
        <content-links>
            <content-link content-id="Number1b" />
        </content-links>
    </content
</library>
```

I would need to get all the content-id that are linked to specific content-id titles. For example, for this case I would need all the ids that are linked for title001 (I might need for more titles, so it would be a list of titles that need to be found). And all these ids be added to a list that would look like:
   [title001, Number1, Number2, Number1b]

So I guess that I need to recursively check every content and then get the content-id from the content-link to go to the next content and check in this one all the content-link going to the next one until the xml is completely read.

I am not able to find the recursive solution to this.

Adding the code that I got until now for this:

```
from lxml import etree as et
def get_ids(content):
    """
    """
    content_links = content.findall('content-links/content-link')
    print(content_links)
    if content_links:
        for content_link in content_links:
            print(content_link,content_link.get('content-id'))
            cl = content_link.get('content-id')
            cont = x.find(f'content[@id="{cl}"]')
            if cont is not None:
                get_ids(cont)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """
    """
    x = et.fromstring(xml)
    ids = ['title001']
    for id in ids:
        content = x.find(f'content[@id="{content-id}"]')
        get_ids(content)
```

Comment: I'm a bit unclear here--so you have a flattened tree structure, or is this a graph with cycles? In other words, can `Number1b` point to `title001`? Is every `content-id` attribute unique? Can you share your code so far? Thanks.

Comment: No, it is a tree. Number1b can only point to a new node, for example Number1bc. So every content-id is unique. I will try to share the code that I have until now next week.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
from lxml import etree as et

parser = et.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = et.parse('Input.xml', parser)
root = tree.getroot()
cidList = ['title001']  # Your source list
cidDct = { x: 0 for x in cidList }
for elem in root.iter('content'):
    cid = elem.attrib.get('content-id', '')
    # print(f'X  {elem.tag:15}  cid:{cid}')
    if cid in cidDct.keys():
        # print(f'** Found:  {cid}')
        for elem2 in elem.iter():
            if elem2 is not elem:
                cid2 = elem2.attrib.get('content-id', '')
                # print(f'XX {elem2.tag:15}  cid:{cid2}')
                if len(cid2) > 0:
                    # print(f'** Add:  {cid2}')
                    cidDct[cid2] = 0
```

For the test you may uncomment printouts above.

Now when you print `list(cidDct.keys())`, you will get the
wanted *ids*:

```
['title001', 'Number1', 'Number2', 'Number1b']
```